# bcp command not defining nullable in format file

Tags: xml, nullable, bcp

I'm using a command like this:

```
bcp "tablename" format nul -w -x -f "Format.xml" -d databasename -S servername -G
```

Which is generating the format file (abridged) like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="42"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="32" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="256" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <!-- ABRIDGED -->

 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="BUSINESS_UNIT" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="SERVICE_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <!-- ABRIDGED -->
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

However the data type in SQL Server for SERVICE_NUMBER is nullable, hence I'd expect this:

```xml
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="SERVICE_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" NULLABLE="YES"/>
```

The -k command seems to be only for importing, whereas I'd like the format file to exist as a way of documenting the known schema that the exported data file represents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, -k is for the "in" operation of BCP. You cannot get the information you are seeking from a format file.

As for getting document to "show the known schema" why not just query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and bcp out their contents?

bcp "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '' order by ORDINAL_POSITION" queryout .... (the rest of our BCP command)

Comment: Thanks Jamie, good point I could have a second supporting file. The bit that struck me was that the nullable attribute is valid in the format file spec, yet the bcp tool doesn't seem to export it?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean when you say "nullable attribute is valid in the format file spec"... can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry yes I should of been clearer, this link mentions it in the XML schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#AttrOfColumnElement

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yes, I see that it is called out and I also do not get the NULLABLE property of the column when I create a xml format file. Odd (Im on SQL 2014). I do not use XML format files much (which is why I did not know about this "nullable" property being in there... well sorta). Okay, I can try a bit more, but looks like it's not included although its documented. I tried a few things, but cannot get it to be included.

Comment: If this really is a problem for MS to solve or if there is some way to get it included that we're missing, then I believe you can work around this by creating your own XML format file. You can query the relevant format file data as an XML result and export that result out as format file. pretty sure that could work, but really hope there is a way to get the Nullable included as MS says it can be.

Comment: Thanks for trying @jamie that's good of you, when I'm back in the office I'll look at raising a feature request and share a link when. It's probably an edge case what I'm doing, but pretty useful for the test suit I'm building up.